# Запрет копирования и присваивания

Tags: c++

У меня есть шаблон класса для хранения динамического списка. Почему надо сделать запрет конструктора копирования и оператора присваивания?

Comment: Сразу не понял вопроса. 

Вопрос слишком общий. Если дадите конкретный код, то можно о чем-то говорить. А так, не вижу причин для запрета.

Comment: Скорее наоборот нужно реализовать эти методы.

Answer (score 1):

Все очень просто. Дело в том, что если Вы в класс включаете указатель (голый) на что-либо, то при копировании объекта или присваивании случится беда. А заключается она в том, что старое значение указателя у присваиваемого объекта сотрется и указатели из двух объектов будут указывать на один адрес. Итого - получаем утечку памяти и в конце-концов обращение по адресу уже освобожденной памяти. Поэтому решений два: или пишем свой конструктор копирования и оператор присваивания, или никогда не используем голые указатели, а используем подходящий к ситуации тип [умного указателя](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C).

В принципе, можно просто запретить присваивание объектов и конструктор копий... Только вот правильное ли это решение - вопрос.

Comment: > а используем подходящий к ситуации тип "умного" указателя.

а можно поподробнее об "умном указателе" ?
что? как? с чем едят? желательно с примерами...
ну или ссылки на рус_faq

Comment: Без конкретного кода все это разговоры ни о чем.

Comment: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C
http://www.rsdn.ru/article/cpp/smartptr.xml
http://how-too-doo-it.blogspot.ru/2009/11/c.html
http://www.kalnitsky.org/2011/11/02/smart-pointers-in-cpp11/

Answer (score 0):

Пример делается просто.

```
class X{
public:
X *prev, *next;
int i;
};

class Y{
protected:
X *up, *end;
};
```

Для простого динамического списка сойдет. Так вот, если не заблокировать копирование в Y, то при копировании указатели up и end скопируются и в итоге две переменных Y будут указывать на один список, а это прямой путь к вылету программы. Когда одна переменная Y удалится, в ее копии up и end будут указывать на неизвестную область памяти и при попытке работать с ней программа будет вылетать.

Comment: @mikelsv, отличный пример, демонстрирующий  сложность (а часто и непонятность) программ на С++.

Comment: > Когда одна переменная Y удалится, в ее копии up и end будут указывать на неизвестную область памяти

Ну, не факт... Скажем так - в зависимости от реализации может быть и так, и наоборот.

Comment: @avp, если это сложный пример, то я китайский летчик. В Y, up указывает на первый элемент массива, end на последний. Сам массив состоит из цепочки переменных X, где prev указывает на предыдущий элемент, а next на следующий.
@gecube, факт в большинстве случаев. Я конечно могу представить реализацию, где будет по другому, но выйдет что-то довольно безумное. В нормальной ситуации, когда есть Y y1, y2; y2=y1; и в y1 были данные, то при удалении y1 указатели в y2 будут указывать на непонятную область, обращение к которой приведет к краху программы.

Comment: @mikelsv, конструктор и деструктор напишите ;) тогда вопросов не будет. Просто все зависит от того, кто и как чистит (освобождает) память. Учитывая, что здесь в примере используются "сырые" указатели, то вся работа с выделением-освобождением памяти осталась за кадром, да и по умолчанию никто ничего не выделяет.

Comment: @mikelsv, с чего Вы решили, что это массив? Это Вы так думаете.

--

Формально объект типа Y просто ссылается на 2 объекта типа X, каждый из которых (ну это уже неформально) является элементом двусвязного списка. На элементы одного или 2-х разных списков находятся ссылки в Y, а также где они размещены (в массиве, выделены в куче и т.д.) неизвестно.

Вот и все, что можно сказать по этим описаниям.

Когда Вы говорите о том, что будет (или не будет) при копировании, то видимо подразумеваете некие конструктор и деструктор, удаляющий *Ваш* массив, которых здесь нет.

Поэтому пример и непонятен.

Comment: согласен с @avp

Comment: Понял, где ошибся. Имел в виду вот такую штуку: http://pastebin.com/CrNmtYi0. У меня кстати не заблокированы оператор копирования и присваивания. Наверно из-за полной уверенности, что никогда не попытаюсь подобного сделать.

Comment: Unknown Paste ID! :-(

Comment: Блин. http://pastebin.com/CrNmtYi0 . Точку записало как элемент адреса.